# Workload planning and generation

Tags: netty, ycsb

I searched for 'Load Test' but didn't find many standard procedures. Does anyone have experience with workload generators for testing Netty servers. 
I found numerous TCP/IP packet generators. 
Anyone have experience with Netty and workload generation for high-speed message processors ?
Are there workload generators like http://research.yahoo.com/Web_Information_Management/YCSB ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on what kind of protocol you want to handle in your netty based server.

For example if you want to test smtp you can do it via smtp-source[1] which is included in the postfix[2] installation. Jmeter[3] also offers a lot of stuff to test all kind of network servers.

[1] http://www.murkycloud.com/2011/10/apache-james-server-smtp-is-fastthank.html

[2] http://www.postfix.org

[3] http://jmeter.apache.org

Comment: Thanks. It is TCP and I was thinking of workload plans/generators based on capacity planning ideas. I cited YCSB because it uses statistics and generates different kinds of workloads. Plotting and graphing are easier because many OSS tools exist.